# converting hexadecimal to byte in java

Tags: java, parsing, hex

I m new in java.I have a text document with hexadecimal values line by line,  i m trying to read it and convert it into byte array. but for the hexadecimal values like 8, d, 11, 0, e4 when parsing i m getting wrong value for e4 as -28 instead of 228.
how can i overcome this conversion error....

```
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/data.txt");

          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(newInputStreamReader(in,"UTF-8"));


          byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
          String str;
          int i=0;

          while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) 
          {

              bytes[i]= (byte) (Integer.parseInt(str,16) & 0xFF);
              i++;

          }
          byte[] destination = new byte[i];
          System.arraycopy(bytes, 0, destination, 0, i);

          br.close();
          return destination;
```

Comment: byte in Java is signed. It's range is - `[-128, 127]`, the value after `127` goes to the negative side. And hence `228` is `-28`.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read text http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/java-memes-which-refuse-to-die.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `Alnitak` said `byte` is signed in java. Value of 0xe4 = 228 which is unsigned, and the range of `byte` is -128 to 127.

My suggestion is to use `int` instead of `byte` like

```
int[] bytes = new int[1024];
bytes[i]= Integer.parseInt(str,16);
```

You get the same thing which you have require.

Comment: chances are he has a good reason to want an array of bytes (i.e. input to some other API call).  The only real reason to convert to an unsigned int is for _presentation purposes_, which should be separated from the internal representation.

Comment: do also note that storing as `int` will require four times more memory than storing them in a `byte` array...

Answer (score 5):

Bytes (and all other integer types) are *signed* in Java, not *unsigned*.

If you're just treating the bytes as a byte array, it doesn't matter that some of the values are negative, their bit representation is still correct.

You can get the "proper" unsigned value by masking the byte value with the `int` value `0xff`, although the resulting value will itselt be an `int` too:

```
int n = (myByte & 0xff);
```

Comment: +1 But it still matters though even if you are treating them as bits and are not just debugging. Why oh why does java have signed... I don't buy the explanation :P